# How to calculate the total memory requirement for an array of struct in C?

Tags: c, arrays, memory, struct

Assume that an integer needs 4 bytes, a real number needs 4 bytes, and a character needs 1
byte of the memory for allocation.
Consider the following definition is given to store 15 years of daily temperatures of 5 cities.

```
struct monYear
{
    int month, year;
};
struct perCity
{
    char cityName[16];
    struct monYear my;
    float temperature[31];
    float avrg;
} fiveCities[5][15];
```

What is the total memory requirement for the array variable fiveCities (how many bytes it
occupies in the memory)?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you think you got it right? What are the alignment requirements of each data type? Please indent the code properly.

Comment: The total memory requirement is whatever `sizeof fiveCities` evaluates to.

Comment: There are some cavaties in calculating the size of varible by hand. The compiler might add padding in your datastructures, because of that the correct way to determine the size of your variable is to just use `sizeof(..)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure you provided is straight forward and can be easily calculated as

```
(16+4+4+31*4+4)*5*15=11400 B
```

(I assume int as 4B which is architecture-specific)

However, structure packing isn't always straight forward, and for instance, the same size is generated when cityName is modified to 15 elements.

This depends on the compiler and architecture, one of the best guide about structure packing can be found here:

http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/

We use the sizeof operator to avoid structure packing confusion, as shown in the example below.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

struct monYear {
  int month, year;
};
struct perCity {
  char cityName[15];
  struct monYear my;
  float temperature[31];
  float avrg;
} fiveCities[5][15];

int main(void) {
  printf("%zu\n", sizeof(fiveCities));
  return 0;
}
```

There is an option to force the compiler to use specific packing size, for instance, the gcc has #pragma pack:

```c
#pragma pack(1)
struct test_structure {
  char byte[1];
  uint32_t dword;
};
#pragma pack()
```

This is usually not recommended but in some cases may be useful. In the example above, the structure size is 5 bytes, whereas without `#pragma pack` it would be 8.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `sizeof` operator.you can use `sizeof(fiveCities)` which is equal to `5*15*sizeof(struct perCity)`.

Answer (score 0):

As a clarification, sizeof is an operator not a function and does not require parenthesizes when finding the size of a value. Parenthesizes are only needed when you want to find the size of a type (sort of like casting).
So in your example you could find your size by either:

```
size_t my_size = sizeof fiveCities;
```

or you could use

```
#define CITIES 5
#define YEARS  15
size_t storage_needed = sizeof(struct perCity) * CITIES * YEARS;
```